# JupyterNotebook: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I've created folder structures with code on my desktop, and filled them with images using the cap=cv2.VideoCapture() with no problem.

To create folder structures and make directories, I wrote this code and it works fine:

```
#SETUP PATHS
POS_PATH = os.path.join('data', 'positive')
NEG_PATH = os.path.join('data', 'negative')
ANC_PATH = os.path.join('data','anchor')


#MAKE DIRECTORIES
os.makedirs(POS_PATH)
os.makedirs(NEG_PATH)
os.makedirs(ANC_PATH)
```

[folderstructures_on_desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsTMc.png)

But, when I want to list images in a file, I get this error:

```
os.listdir('positive')
```

> ERROR: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path
> specified: 'positive'

Can you help me?

Comment: You mean os.listdir(POS_PATH)

Comment: `os.listdir('positive')` uses folder name that is relative to what Python thinks is the current working directory, which novices assume is the folder where the running program is located. It normally isn't. Specify the full path in the `os.listdir()`call.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;rd**

```
os.listdir('data/positive')
```

---

**Detailed answer**:

If you will use the following command:

```
os.listdir('positive')
```

you will get the `FileNotFoundError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f6aeca1b018e> in <module>
----> 1 os.listdir('positive')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'positive'
```

The reason for that is that the actual location of this directory is:

```
'data/positive'
```

See the proper command below:

```
os.listdir('data/positive')
```

I prepared an example Jupyter Notebook presenting this case. I hope that you will find this example useful: https://gist.github.com/mikbuch/73401b8fa7289113417b35f1144cb179